# monitoring OOM with Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I'd like to utilise Prometheus to monitor occurences of system OOM killer on Debian / Ubuntu. The particular case is that sometimes Redis is killed because of OOM and the already existing low-memory-available alert is not triggered because it happens too fast. But I'd like to make the solution as smart and universal as possible and also not to spend a lot of time on it, so let us not focus on Redis itself. The ideas I have so far:

- use existing memory-related Prometheus metrics, only trigger them on extremely low values (ie. 1% memory left) and low "for" values (ie. 5 seconds) - this solution might work and is very simple to implement, but I believe it might be unreliable (not necessarily triggering on all OOMs and only on OOMs)
- create a bash script periodically checking dmesg and creating metrics based on appropriate grep results - is likely to work, but the problem might be with properly recognizing dmesg messages already grepped from the new ones (do not alert on the same OOM twice); also this solution is not very elegant
- create a custom Prometheus exporter - if written properly is likely to work as expected, but creating it might be a lot of work, which I'd like to avoid

I'd like to ask for your suggestions and opinions. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `node_vmstat_oom_kill` metric from the node exporter will tell you this.

Comment: Thanks. This is based on `/proc/vmstat` btw. Here is an alert which uses this metric which can be used pretty much as-is in your local Prometheus alerting rules: https://awesome-prometheus-alerts.grep.to/rules.html